# Flash Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference ....?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, methods, reference

I have a problem when I create a menu with flash as3. Can you guys help what should I do ...? Like this :

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at DocumentClass/menuScreen()
at DocumentClass/mouseBack()
```

how to right code to fix the code below:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.system.fscommand;
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;

public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip {
public var backbutton:BackButton = new BackButton();
    public function DocumentClass() {
        menuScreen();
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, masukGame);

    }
    public function masukGame(e:Event):void{
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    }
    public function menuScreen():void{

        game.menuscreen.mb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick1);
        game.menuscreen.pb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick2);
        game.menuscreen.mlb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick3);
        game.menuscreen.kb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick4);


    }
    public function backMenu():void{

        backbutton.buttonMode = true;
        backbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseBack);
        backbutton.x = 450;
        backbutton.y = 400;
        // Dan akhirnya letakan button ke stage;
        addChild(backbutton);
        backbutton.visible=true;

    }

    public function mouseClick1(event:MouseEvent):void {
        game.gotoAndStop("MainGame");
        backMenu();


    }
    public function mouseClick2(event:MouseEvent):void {
        game.gotoAndStop("Petunjuk");
        backMenu();
    }
    public function mouseClick3(event:MouseEvent):void {
        game.gotoAndStop("Malaria");
        backMenu();
    }
    public function mouseClick4(event:MouseEvent):void {
        game.gotoAndStop("Keluar");
        backMenu();
    }
    public function mouseBack(event:MouseEvent):void {

        menuScreen();


    }   


    }
}
```

And this is my file, download here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jo7bcwnlfj7qjnh/My%20Game.rar

Please help me, and thanks guys ...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a **Null Pointer Exception**.
It means that you are trying to access a variable inside a null object.

The StackTrace you provided guide us to the problem.
The last place in the trace are:

```
DocumentClass/menuScreen()
```

So, your problem is inside the `menuScreen()` of the `DocumentClass` class.

```
public function menuScreen():void
{
    game.menuscreen.mb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick1);
    game.menuscreen.pb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick2);
    game.menuscreen.mlb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick3);
    game.menuscreen.kb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick4);
}
```

Here we try to access:

- `game`
- `game.menuscreen`
- `game.menuscreen.mb`
- `game.menuscreen.pb`
- `game.menuscreen.mlb`
- `game.menuscreen.kb`

One of this are null.

---

**EDIT 1**

Ok, I tried your code *.fla* and found out that the problem is the `game.menuscreen` call.
Once you change your screen you remove the `menuscreen` from the stage.

When you get back and try to access it, it doesn't exist anymore, so, you get an NPE (*Null Pointer Exception*).

---

**EDIT 2**

You can solve the problem with different approaches, but the easiest (and least flexible) is to keep a reference to your `menuscreen` somewhere you can get it latter.

E.g.: You can keep it in the `DocumentClass` class this way:

```
public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip
{
    public var backbutton:BackButton = new BackButton();
    public var gameMenuScreen:MovieClip;

    public function DocumentClass()
    {
        gameMenuScreen = game.menuscreen;
        menuScreen();
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, masukGame);
    }

    // ... rest of the class
}
```

Then you can access it directly from the `DocumentClass`, this way:

```
public function menuScreen():void
{
    // It was "game.menuscreen"
    // Now it is "gameMenuScreen"

    gameMenuScreen.mb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick1);
    gameMenuScreen.pb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick2);
    gameMenuScreen.mlb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick3);
    gameMenuScreen.kb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClick4);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code or solution that I have to do??? because I was new bee ... for Flash ... please and thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the flash to the Version of another kind. I experimented with it and the problem went away.